# How to create parent Guice injector in main with RESTEasy and embedded jetty

Tags: java, java-8, guice, resteasy

I have a catch 22 problem while designing REST micro services using RESTEasy. I'm trying to create an application with an embedded jetty server to reduce deployment complexity. Therefore, I have a main method that creates a jetty server. I need to inject some object before the server's bootstrap procedure.

My main looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    App app = new App();
    // Need to inject app here.
    app.init(args);
    app.start();        
}
```

How can I get the Injector singleton instance so I can inject my app object?

Answer (score 0):

Delegate creation of App to injector too. And pass args to constructor of your module. Like this:

```
class App {
    @Inject
    public App(@Named("args") String[] args, Server jettyServer) {
        //...
    }
}

class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final String[] args;

    public MyModule(String[] args) {
        this.args = args;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(String[].class).annotatedWith(Names.named("args")).toInstance(args);
    }
}

main(String[] args) {
    App app = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule(args)).getInstance(App.class);
}
```